# Laravel - How to format coalesce to decimal places in Laravel

Tags: laravel

In Laravel-5.8, I have this as part of query which is working fine:

```
DB::raw('(COALESCE(COUNT(lr.leave_status), 0) / COALESCE(COUNT(e.id), 0) * 100) as perc_applied'),
```

When I did this:

```
DB::raw('(number_format(COALESCE(COUNT(lr.leave_status), 0) / COALESCE(COUNT(e.id), 0) * 100), 2) as perc_applied'),
```

I got this error:

> production.ERROR: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1305 FUNCTION

How do I format to 2 decimal places?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using mysql [FORMAT](https://www.w3schools.com/SQl/func_mysql_format.asp)() function:

The FORMAT() function formats a number to a format like "#,###,###.##", rounded to a specified number of decimal places, then it returns the result as a string.

```
  DB::raw('FORMAT(((COALESCE(COUNT(lr.leave_status), 0) / COALESCE(COUNT(e.id), 1) * 100)),2) as perc_applied');
```

Comment: How do I do it when  COALESCE(COUNT(e.id), 0) is null or 0 , since I'm using it to divide, so that it won't throw error?

Comment: it should be :COALESCE(COUNT(e.id), 1), is not?